# Default max color values in cylindrical coordinates

Tags: c#, .net, colors, pinvoke

Basically I need to know the valid range for H, L, and S in the win32 functions like `ColorHLSToRGB(H, L, S)`.

---

edit: The basic premise of this question is wrong. Inverting in this way does not always give a contrasting color especially when the color to be contrasted against is near gray. I ended up using black or white as my contrast color.
It would still be nice to have this answered and know what HLSMAX is by default though.

---

I'm trying to get a contrasting color for text given a background color. To that end, I've written the following code but I'm not sure what the range of values for H, L, and S are. 240 seems to be the number given on a few sites (see references I've used below and/or google HLSMAX for yourself) but that's so low that precision will be lost. Doesn't seem right... Not to mention I'm not getting a contrasting color. Color looks the same.

*Questionable part is value of HLSMAX at first line in contrastColor*

```
        [DllImport("shlwapi.dll")]
        static extern void ColorRGBToHLS(int RGB, ref int H, ref int L, ref int S);

        [DllImport("shlwapi.dll")]
        static extern RGB ColorHLSToRGB(int H, int L, int S);

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct RGB
        {
            public byte r, g, b;
            public RGB(Color colorIn)
            {
                r = colorIn.R;
                g = colorIn.G;
                b = colorIn.B;
            }
            public Int32 ToInt32()
            { return BitConverter.ToInt32(new byte[4] {r, g, b, 0},0); }
            public Color ToColor()
            { return Color.FromRgb(r, g, b); }
        }

        private Color contrastColor(Color color)
        {
            int HLSMAX=240;//Is this right??? It seems too low!
            RGB rgb = new RGB(color);
            int h=0, l=0, s=0;
            ColorRGBToHLS(rgb.ToInt32(), ref h, ref l, ref s);
            h=(h+(HLSMAX/2))%HLSMAX;
            l = HLSMAX - l;
            rgb = ColorHLSToRGB(h, l, s);
            return Color.FromArgb(color.A, rgb.r, rgb.g, rgb.b);
        }
```

References used:

- [MSN 'How to' on converting colors](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/29240)
- [Wikipedia article detailing cylindrical color coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV)
- [Pinvoke.net entry for colorhlstorgb](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/shlwapi.colorhlstorgb)
- [Pinvoke.net entry for colorrgbtohls](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/shlwapi.colorrgbtohls)

Comment: So from here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/144/CColor-RGB-and-HLS-combined-in-one-class They seem to refer to the Hue part as 0 to 360 (since it's circle shaped), and the light and saturation is 0 to 1.  Maybe this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft's website doesn't seem to include the values.
However, the WINE API documentation states the values are 0-240.

https://source.winehq.org/WineAPI/ColorRGBToHLS.html

Comment: This doesn't exactly give a root source reference but that's the closest I've seen. If it's good enough for wine, it's good enough for me.

Answer (score 0):

Rich Newman has created an [HSLColor Class](http://richnewman.wordpress.com/about/code-listings-and-diagrams/hslcolor-class/). You might find using this is better then using Win32 functions.

To answer your original question, Rich Newman's class seems to use 240 as the value you are seeking.